# How to prevent MacVim from inherenting .profile as if it was Bash itself?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, .profile

I have this guard in my `.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi

    if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bash_aliases"
    fi
fi
```

Still, I have verified the check is passing for MacVim started from Finder, not only from bash terminal, and `.bashrc` contains terminal related script that seems to make MacVim not work as expected when started by double click, so I must have this check failing for non-terminal executions. I'm not sure whether this affects MacVim only or just any application. I was expecting `$BASH_VERSION` empty for anything started from Finder.

Any tips?

Comment: I'd do debugging.... Id have some temp code in your .profile that dumps all env vars to a file. Then run it once as a shell, then run MacVim, see if MacVim sets something you can detect and put guard code around.

Comment: @RichHomolka I started using `$TERM_PROGRAM` instead of `$BASH_VERSION` in OS X now, this one works, tks again.